# Angular JS $timeout vs $interval

Tags: angularjs

What's the difference? When should I use which? I am new to Angular & they look very similar to me. I would rather follow best practices from the start.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`$interval`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) executes a callback repeatedly, while [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) simply delays the execution of a callback (doesn't repeat). So, no, they're not the same. Additionally, it should be noted that both of them are wrappers for [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) respectively.

I would also like to recommend to read [this great article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) written by John Resig on how Javascript timers work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some info extracted from [djvirgen's](https://www.reddit.com/user/djvirgen) response to [a similar Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/3gzb0d/timeout_vs_settimeout/):

> You should always be using $timeout in Angular apps. Here's why:
>
> - It's injectable, making testing easier with ngMock.
> - It runs a digest to ensure your view is updated.
> - It is thenable (it's also a promise).
>
> However, if you don't want a digest to run, you can simply pass false as the third argument.

I would guess **$interval** has similar advantages.