# how to add parameter to the function in angular interval

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a function which will iterate through an array with some time interval.

```
eg:arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

And I want to show each element with angular interval.

```
$interval(step,5000,7);
function step(i){
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

So it'll output the numbers inside the array in a 5 seconds' interval. How can I pass the parameter into the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this way:

```
var arrOrig =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 
    arr = angular.copy(arrOrig), //if you want it for later
    cancelPromise = $interval(step, 5000);

function step() {
  console.log(arr.shift()); //take out the item from top of array
  if (!arr.length) { //once array runs out
    $interval.cancel(cancelPromise); //cancel interval
  }
}
```

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var $interval = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$interval');
var cancelPromise = $interval(step, 5000);

function step() {
  console.log(arr.shift());
  if (!arr.length) {
    $interval.cancel(cancelPromise);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
$interval(function(){
   step(i);
   i++
},5000);

function step(i){
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.forEach(function (number, idx) {
    $timeout(function () {
        console.log(number);
    }, 5000 * (idx + 1));
});
```

You want to use `$timeout` rather than `$interval` because calling `$interval` will set up an interval each time for each number and it won't stop until it's cleared explicitly.

Comment: I want to output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 with 5 seconds interval each. And I've already specify the steps in the interval so it only iterate 7 times.

Comment: @Gabriel I see; you can still use my code to do this though: http://plnkr.co/edit/ywlowWztJiTaXfqHJNvu?p=preview

Comment: yes, your code work perfectly. I'm just wondering whether it works with interval

Answer (score 0):

This code will display the numbers one at a time, on repeat:

```
var getNextNumber = (function(){
    var i = 0;
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    return function(){
        if(i >= numbers.length){
            i = 0;
        }
        return numbers[i++];
    };
})();

$interval(function(){
    var number = getNextNumber();
    console.log(number);
},5000);
```

See this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqs7aktp/3/).

If you want to display them only once, use one of the `$timeout` solutions from one of the other answers.  `$interval` is all about repeating some command for an indefinite amount of time, whereas `$timeout` is more about performing a command once in the future. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105646/angular-js-timeout-vs-interval) for more.