# Directive's view doesn't reflect model changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out why directive's controller doesn't update data

```
angular.module('sample', [])
.directive('countdown', function () {

function CountdownController() {
    var countdownController = this;

    countdownController.digit = 5;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('fired');
        countdownController.digit = 200;
    }, 3000);

}


return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: CountdownController,
    controllerAs: 'countdownController',
    bindToController: true,
    template: '{{countdownController.digit}}'
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mghs52my/

I know I can use $scope.$apply() to force changes, but why should I do that?

Comment: Maybe using the $timeout service from Angular helps (not using setTimeout - which is plain JS). Therefore you wouldn't need to call $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is  outside of any of angular's core services or directives. Whenever you change scope from outside of the core you need to use `$apply()`.

For this reason angular has `$timeout` which is a wrapper for `setTimout()` and will call `$apply()` internally

Change to:

```
angular.module('sample', [])
    .directive('countdown', function ($timeout) {

    function CountdownController() {
        var countdownController = this;

        countdownController.digit = 5;

        $timeout(function () {
            console.log('fired');
            countdownController.digit = 200;
        }, 3000);

    }


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: CountdownController,
        controllerAs: 'countdownController',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '{{countdownController.digit}}'
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mghs52my/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to change you model in each time after some time interval
>
> use **$interval** instead of **setTimeout()**

```
angular.module('sample', [])
    .directive('countdown', function () {

    function CountdownController($interval) {
        var countdownController = this;

        countdownController.digit = 5;

        $interval(function () {
            console.log('fired');
            countdownController.digit = 200;
        }, 3000);

    }


    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: CountdownController,
        controllerAs: 'countdownController',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '{{countdownController.digit}}'
    }
});
```

> ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout) and [setTimeout or setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)
>
> [$timeout vs $interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105646/angular-js-timeout-vs-interval)

Comment: huh? $interval is recurring, a timeout is not...they do different things

Comment: @charlietfl - agree, let me add this one in answer, thanks.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar yeah, I know the difference between them. but when you are using setInterval you have to be sure callback function will be completely executed before next call. I agree in the example it isn't an issue.