# Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds

Tags: angular

I have an integration test that gives me the error `Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds`

And so I opened the Chrome browser performance tab and saw a lot of yellow ticks indicating scripting activity all along the recorded timeline.

I can see there is this `globalZoneAwareCallback` method call being fired constantly.

Where is this call coming from ? How can I have my test not wait for ever and timeout ?

There is no network activity at all.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/971

Answer (score 0):

Try using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`. Also check : [How does waitForAngularEnabled work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648077/how-does-waitforangularenabled-work)